# Running Storybook on an Angular Library Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, storybook, angular-storybook

I created a new Angular Workspace.

```
ng new workspace --create-application=false
cd workspace
```

And then generated a library within the workspace.

```
ng g library lib
```

I also generated a playground for testing the library.

```
ng g application playground
```

Then I initialized storybook and tried to run it.

```
npx storybook@latest init
npm run storybook
```

When attempting to run storybook it logs this error:

```
info => Using angular project "lib:build" for configuring Storybook
ERR! Error: error TS6053: File '../false' not found.
ERR!
ERR!     at readTsconfig (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/workspace/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/read-tsconfig.js:51:15)
ERR!     at async configureI18nBuild (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/workspace/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/i18n-options.js:125:22)
ERR!     at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/workspace/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:67:36)
ERR!  Error: error TS6053: File '../false' not found.
ERR!
ERR!     at readTsconfig (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/workspace/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/read-tsconfig.js:51:15)
ERR!     at async configureI18nBuild (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/workspace/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/i18n-options.js:125:22)
ERR!     at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/workspace/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:67:36)

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.

info => Loading presets
✔ Would you like to send crash reports to Storybook? … yes
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the workspace where your library is located, you should have a `.storybook` directory. Well, in that directory you will have a `tsconfig.json` file. Edit line 1, which you currently have as:

```
    "extends": "../false"
```

to

```
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json".
```

And don't forget to also add the "include" path

```
"../stories/**/*"
```

Comment: Awesome!!  I added a request for Storybook to update their support for Angular library projects here: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21657

Comment: Fixed ... and then some other goodies too ... https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/storybook-for-angular-library-projects-a43893d2c50d